# Adding values without sign-extension?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sign-extension

I know that the CPU doesn't care about the sign bit, because of two's complement. But when using different operand sizes, then the source value gets sign extended to the destination's size.

```
xor rax, rax
add rax, byte 0xAD ; adds 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAD to RAX
```

**Is there an** `add` **instruction that adds values without sign-extension (and avoids null bytes)?**

(I'm working with a x86_64 architecture)

Comment: Not with an immediate. You can go through a register.

Comment: So `add r64, r8` is not a sign-extended addition?

Comment: There is no `add r64, r8`.

Comment: Sorry. `r64` and `r8` should mean 64-bit register and 8-bit register

Comment: There is no such instruction. You will use `add r64, r64` after you load your immediate into a 64 bit register zero extended. `mov cl, 0xad; movzx ecx, cl; add rax, rcx` (note that 32 bit ops zero extend automatically).

Comment: Ahhh, ok, now it works :D Thank you